# Why does my C# code pick up some JSON URLs but not others?

Tags: c#, json, database, unity-game-engine, iot

I'm trying to create my own JSON file to be read in Unity 3D, however I can't get it to work. My code is fine with JSON URLs I haven't created however. What can I do with my JSON to ensure it is picked up in Unity/C#?

I've tried exporting my Google Sheet to JSON using the basic method, then went to using Sheetsu, but no luck. It works with the example JSON url though...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GoogleSheetJSON : MonoBehaviour


{

public GameObject GSvariable;
IEnumerator UpdateText()
{
    while (true)
    {
            //First attempt
            //string jsonUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1wqo8gFMC6FHo7G3mrMVZap-eGsp1Z-nxaQ2AcAQ4dKk/1/public/full?alt=json";

            //Second attempt
            //string jsonUrl = "https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/f54be9f9d696";

            //External JSON url
            string jsonUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

            WWW googleSheetWWW = new WWW(jsonUrl);
        yield return googleSheetWWW;

        JSONObject tempData = new JSONObject(googleSheetWWW.text);

            //First attempt
            //Debug.Log(tempData["entry"]["0"]["gs$cell"]["inputValue"]);
            //GSvariable.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = tempData["entry"]["0"]["gs$cell"]["inputValue"].ToString();

            //Second attempt
            //Debug.Log(tempData["timestamp"]);
            //GSvariable.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = tempData["timestamp"].ToString();

            //External JSON url
            Debug.Log(tempData["title"]);
            GSvariable.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = tempData["title"].ToString();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(60);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(UpdateText());
}
}
```

I think it's obvious that the management of my JSON files is not correct, however I can't understand why they wouldn't work considering they're on a public URL.

When I uncomment my second attempt, I'm expecting to see my placeholder text "Google Sheet =" to become ", Test 4" yet I get the following Unity error on play:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GoogleSheetJSON+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GoogleSheetJSON.cs:36)

[Screen grab of error if 'Second attempt' is uncommented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn479.png)
[Screen grab of code as described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eLzC.png)

Comment: need more information like JSON??

Comment: Hi Matt. Few questions. Why is there a while(true) with a yield return? `First` and `second` attempt code will not be executed I think. It probably is not in the URL, but in the file that the URL points to. What is the content of the JSON file you have in the URL? It says it goes wrong on line 36 in GoogleSheetJSON. THe code you posted has commented code at line 36. WHat is the actual code ATM of the error?

Comment: I tried your code. If you are using SimpleJSON, `JSONObject` doesn't take arguments. Use JSONNode instead it works for me. Also @MikedeKlerk is right.

Comment: Thanks for response. This code has worked for sourcing data from a weather api, so I've only edited the parts I've needed to. I've commented out the First and Second Attempts to test with the External URL. I've also updated the images. First image shows an error produced by linking to the JSON url I created; second image shows it working with the third party JSON url and code described in the question.

Comment: Does that mean changing line 28 to "JSONNode tempData = new JSONNode(googleSheetWWW.text);"

Comment: This is the statement `JSONNode tempData = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(googleSheetWWW.text);`